# How to display a relation within a relation using BindingSource WinForms

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio, data-binding

I have 3 tables I am trying to show a relation between. In table 1 I have a Primary ID field, and this has a relation to Table 2 that has a multiples of that Primary ID contained within it.

```
IE:
Table 1

PID        ||  Name
======================
123        ||  SomeName


Table 2
Second ID ||  PID  || Code_ID
===============================
1        ||  123  ||  55
2        ||  123  ||  66


Table 3
Code ID   ||  Code_Description
===============================
55        ||  Some Description 1
66        ||  Some Description 2
```

I am using Windows Forms with a data grid view using data bindings and relations in my dataset. I have a relation between PID in Table 1 and PID in Table 2. I can set a databinding to that relation and it will show me the 1-many row relation in the two. I then created a relation between Table 2 Code_ID and Table 3 Code_ID. I created another databinding using the relation between PIDs as the data source, and my new Code_ID as the data member. However this only displays one row from Table 3 with the correct description.

What I would like to do is have Code_ID displayed in the one-many PID relation to show description that is contained in Table 3, I have no idea how to do this.

I apologize if this is unclear, but it is as best I can describe it with my limited understanding of these controls. I am new to DB programming and any advice would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: have tried querying server by Joins?

Comment: I do have a query solution to it that works in SQL server, but I was hoping to be able to do it systematically using the designer. Reason being is that I have a list populated with my first table, as you scroll through that list, the labels on the form automatically update to that related selection through data bindings and relations. I have been able to work this with 1-1 relations and 1-many relations but only between two tables. I now have a new list that populates a list of codes related to that business's unique PID, but I wish for them to show their description that is in another table.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem ended up being using a SQL command with a DataTable.

To clarify the original problem some, I have a list bound to a BindingSource that the user may scroll through. As they scroll through the list of entries in that table, relevant entries in other tables are displayed. In this case it was a relation between three tables.

I set a function to the CurrentChanged event for the list BindingSource. In this, I query the database using an inner join between table 2 and 3, with a condition at the end (where table2.PID = "bindingsource pid"{I used a DataRowView with BindingSource.Current, casted with DataRowView to grab the relevant table1 bindingsource PID}

Example code if anyone finds themselves in this scenario:

```
private void ListBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)ListBindingSource.Current;
    string query = "Inner Join SQL Query Table 2 & 3 /w Where PID = rowView[PIDColumn]";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("SQL Connection");
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable SQLResultTable = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(SQLResultTable);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = SQLResultTable;
    }
```